# Traversing an XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml such as below,

```
<product>
  <ProductId>3</ProductId>
  <ProductName>Voice Recognition</ProductName>
</product>
<product>
  <ProductId>5</ProductId>
  <ProductName>TravelExpert Settings</ProductName>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>AllowbookIncompleteTraveller</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>CreateTravs</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>MultiPax</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Hotel</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Profile</Name>
    <Description>true</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Air</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>TicketDelivery</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Exchange</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Car</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>Itinerary</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
  <ProductAttribute>
    <Name>StoredFare</Name>
    <Description>false</Description>
  </ProductAttribute>
</product>
```

I need to traverse to Product with ProductName = "TravelExpert Settings", under which I need the value of ProductAttribute with Name = "Profile". The value is true. The type of the element is System.Xml.Linq.XElement.

May I please have some help with this? Please let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Couple of options. You can use [.NET Serialization support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx) and simply model the objects, deserialize, then use LINQ to find the value you need.  Second option is to use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) to find needed node.

Comment: Yeah the team I work with, is not very savvy on those concepts. That was my first recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You XML is invalid. XML document cannot contain multiple root elements. I assumed your document looks like that:

   ```
   <products>
     <product>
       <ProductId>3</ProductId>
       <ProductName>Voice Recognition</ProductName>
     </product>
     <product>
       <ProductId>5</ProductId>
       <ProductName>TravelExpert Settings</ProductName>
       <ProductAttribute>
         <Name>AllowbookIncompleteTraveller</Name>
         <Description>false</Description>
       </ProductAttribute>
       <!-- (...) -->
     </product>
   </products>
   ```
2. Your query should look like that:

   ```
   var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

   var valueElement = xDoc.Root
                          .Elements("product")
                          .First(p => (string)p.Element("ProductName") == "TravelExpert Settings")
                          .Elements("ProductAttribute")
                          .First(pa => (string)pa.Element("Name") == "Profile")
                          .Element("Description");

   var value = (bool)valueElement;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help out, I tried it and getting the error "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"

Comment: it was not working in the immediate window, but the logic is flawless. May thanks.